# Why does the variable lose its value after exiting for loop?

Tags: c++

I'm new in the programming world. I couldn't find anything related online.
My variable `num` doesn't hold the value assigned to it inside the `for` loop.

It keeps getting 0 after it exits the loop. I'm pretty sure I have done this before: initialize a variable before a `for` loop, change its value inside `for` and then use it outside the `for` loop.

```
//num holds the number that shows how many values of
//... array A are bigger than the values on array B
int num{};
for (int i = 0; i < LINES; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++)
    {
        num = (A[i][j] > B[i][j] ? num++ : num );
    }
}
std::cout << num << " values of array A are bigger than"
                 << " the values of array B" << '\n';
```

Comment: It doesn't lose it's value, it never changes it. Do you know how the post increment works?

Comment: I voted to close as incomplete, but then I saw the problem, so I'd change my vote to caused-by-a-typo if I could. You just need to actually know what operators do before using them. This is a great example of how post-inc/decrement are dangerous to use by default, and should only be used if you actually know and want their rather odd effects.

Comment: `if (A[i][j] > B[i][j]) { ++num; }` is the correct way to write that. All the ternary does in this case is make the code hard to read, and as you've seen, error prone.

Comment: instead of the ternary operator `num = condition? ifTrue : ifFalse` use a simple (and more readable in this case) `if (condition) num++;` without any assignment to num.

Comment: When the condition is true, that conditional is equivalent to `num = num++;`. Don't do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The post increment `num++` will increment `num` but return its old value.

You probably meant

```
num = (A[i][j] > B[i][j] ? num + 1 : num );
```

or, a bit shorter and a bit clearer in my opinion

```
if(A[i][j] > B[i][j]) { num++; }
```

Comment: An option which is shorter, but a bit less clear IMHO, is `num += (A[i][j] > B[i][j])` since a `bool` values of `true` and `false` are converted implicitly to integers `1` and `0` respectively.   I personally consider it unclear, but have encountered programmers who think such a construct is a thing of beauty.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the for loop, you are assigning to `num` one of 2 possible values:

```
num = num;
```

which obviously doesn't change the value of `num`.

And:

```
num = num++;
```

Until C++17 this is undefined behavior, and the code might do anything at all.

From C++17, this is well defined. The way post increment works is that the *old* value of `num` is returned from the expression first. This is `0`. Then `num` is incremented to `1`. However, the old value of `0` is then assigned to `num` on the left hand side, and so the value of `num` is reset to `0`.

Rewriting `num = num++` a little would look like this:

```
old = num;  // old is 0
num++;      // num is 1
num = old   // num is 0
```

which makes it clearer what's happening.

Since `num` never changes inside the loop, the value of `num` is `0` when the loop exits.

---

You could instead write the line that modifies `num` like this:

```
num += (A[i][j] > B[i][j]);
```

Comment: A small explanation, why num+=A[i][j]>B[i][j] is good: when you use an if or ?: (thats if, too) the cpu does not previously know what to do and therefore struggles with the pipeline (start executing next command before previous is finished). When you just always add the result of the comparison (0 or 1) to you number, there are more additions (add 0) to execute, but since that ist totally predictable it is faster anyway.

Comment: Less code is not always easier to read. This is a matter of taste, but in this case I'd strongly recommand to go with an `if (condition) { effect }`. `num += A > B` requires to know the promotion/conversion _bool_ -> _int_ and because we read from left to right makes me in a first step parse `num += A ...(something)` then realize this really should be `num += (A > B)` instead and in a third step wonder why this as been written like this.

Comment: @YSC I read the question as asking for an explanation of why the code doesn't change the value of `num`. I later realized that the OP probably wanted an alternative that worked as well. At that point, other answers had already been provided, so I added a new one. I'm not recommending it per se, though I don't think it's too bad. I agree about grouping the rhs, so I've added parentheses.

Comment: Your explanation is spot on! My first comment is just what it is: a comment on a detail of yoru answer.

Answer (score -1):

`num++` increments `num` and then returns the **previous** value. That means that

```
num = num++;
```

is equal to

```
num = num;
```

You are looking for `++num`, which increases `num` and then returns the **new** value.

Comment: This is not fixing the bad design - if you use `++num`, there's no need to assign the value of `num` again.

Comment: @DrNobody Don't. This is terrible programming. See other answers.

Comment: @DrNobody I agree with YSC. It's bad programming to do it like `num = ++num` and you should do it differently. I wrote the answer this way, because it is the direct answer to your question. It does not include a recommendation on style!